# How to pass $(this) reference to a call back function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have the following animations in my web page:

```
     $(".anim-item").not(this).animate({
        opacity: 0,
     }, { queue: true, duration: 1000 } , function() {
        // Animation complete.
     });

     $(this).animate({
        left: 200,
     }, { queue: true, duration: 1000 } , function() {
        // Animation complete.
     });
```

Currently both the animations are running simultaneously. I want the second animation to run after the first one. I tried putting the second one inside the callback function, but cannot find a way to get the $(this) reference working. Any idea how to get this working?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your function is wrong**, if you are declaring options, then the callback goes in the options object:

```
$(".anim-item").animate({
   opacity: 1,
}, {duration: 1000, queue: true, complete: function() {
   $(this).animate({
      left: 200,
   }, { queue: true, duration: 1000, complete: function() {
      // Animation complete.
   }});
}});
```

Also, don't make a global variable containing the item, that's just asking for trouble, especially as jquery will maintain it for you in this instance, if you need to declare a new variable for the object in chaining, generally you are not doing it right ;)

Answer (score 2):

Two ways:

- cache `this` in a local variable before calling `.animate()`
- use `.proxy()` to pass your `this` reference to `.animate()`

**example 1:**

```
var func = function(){
   var self = this;

   $(".anim-item").not(this).animate({
     opacity: 0,
     }, { queue: true, duration: 1000 } , function() {
        self.animate({});
     });
};
```

**example 2:**

```
var func = function(){
   $.proxy($(".anim-item").not(this).animate({
   }), this);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Save it under a different name, like this:

```
 var myThis = this;
 $(".anim-item").not(this).animate({
    opacity: 0,
 }, { queue: true, duration: 1000 } , function() {
    $(myThis).animate({
       left: 200,
    }, { queue: true, duration: 1000 } , function() {
       // Animation complete.
    });
 });
```

The closure of the inner function will make sure it's visible.

Answer (score 0):

Make an alias for this via

```
var _this = this;
```

If you write a jQuery query `$('.abc')` and use functions like `click`, `hover` etc, `this` will always reference to current DOM node jQuery is processing.

Answer (score 0):

Store this in a local variable.

```
var _this = this;

$(".anim-item").not(this).animate({
        opacity: 0,
    }, { queue: true, duration: 1000 } , function() {
        // Animation complete. Next animation
        $(_this).animate({
            left: 200,
        }, { queue: true, duration: 1000 } , function() {
            // Animation complete.
        });
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In a jQuery callback function `this` is always set to the DOM element that the function applies to.

If you want access to `this` in your first callback function you'll have to create a reference to it before you animate:

```
 var self = this;
 $(".anim-item").not(this).animate({
    opacity: 0,
 }, { queue: true, duration: 1000 } , function() {
    $(self).animate({
        left: 200,
     }, { queue: true, duration: 1000 } , function() {
        // Animation complete.
     });
 });
```